# Why isn't my dynamically generated element appearing on screen?

Tags: jquery, button, element

I’m using jQuery 1.12.  I’m having trouble dynamically appending an element to my document.  To simplify things, I tried running this in the Google developer console …

```
$parent = $('.add-button').parent()
[div.scenarioRole]
```

and then

```
$('<button>').attr({
      name: 'remove-button',
      class: 'remove-button'
    }).appendTo($parent)
[button.remove-button]
```

However, although the second statement indicates an element has been created, I don’t actually see it on screen.  What do I need to do differently in the above to get my element to appear on screen?

Comment: This works in JSFiddle. If you do an *Inspect Element*, do you see the button in the DOM? Being that you've given the button no text, it's very possible that it's just not appearing because it has no content.

Comment: I thiink you're right.  I tried adding a "value: 'some text'" into the above, but I still don't see the button with my text.  It is indeed ther ein the DOM though